# shape file and sf data-frame geometry into latitude longitude columns

Tags: r, latitude-longitude, r-sf, r-sp

I have a simple shape file with multipolygons [.shp file data](https://%20https://data.imas.utas.edu.au/attachments/275f62b0-0b6c-4514-90c7-deeae423ab23/MarineFutures_GeographeBay_reef.zip)

read data into R

```
shp <- st_read("/home/rdfleay/Desktop/R/WestAustralia/GeographeBay/data/gb_gensub50a.shp") # sf()
```

attempt projection, wanting lat lon, but data remains in meters..

```
shp_t <- st_transform(shp, crs = st_crs(shp))
```

project using 'standard' to get lat-lon

```
shp_4326 = st_transform(shp, "EPSG:4326") #
```

i am trying to get the geometry as columns of 'lat' & 'lon'

```
reef_GBay <- shp_4326 %>% 
   filter(Substrate == "Reef")

nrow(reef_GBay)

t(reef_GBay)

print(reef_GBay$geometry)

head(reef_GBay$geometry)

as.data.frame(reef_GBay)
head(reef_GBay$geometry)
```

so far the output remains a single row??
thanks for the help

Comment: `sfheaders::sf_to_df(reef_GBay)` will convert `sf` objects in to long data.frames

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `st_coordinates()` to get the matrix of coordinates and coerce it to data frame:

```r
url <- "https://data.imas.utas.edu.au/attachments/275f62b0-0b6c-4514-90c7-deeae423ab23/MarineFutures_GeographeBay_reef.zip"
f <- "file.zip"
download.file(url, f, mode = "wb")

unzip(f, exdir = "junk", junkpaths = TRUE)

library(sf)

shp <- st_read("junk/gb_gensub50a.shp")
#> Reading layer `gb_gensub50a' from data source 
#> Simple feature collection with 4 features and 2 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 321407.5 ymin: 6279315 xmax: 339012.5 ymax: 6289742
#> Projected CRS: GDA94 / MGA zone 50


# To get lon/lat

library(dplyr)

df <- shp %>%
  # 1. Project to lon/lat
  st_transform(4326) %>%
  # Your filter
  filter(Substrate == "Reef") %>%
  # 2 Extract coordinates
  st_coordinates() %>%
  # 3 to table /tibble
  as.data.frame()

head(df)
#>          X         Y L1 L2 L3
#> 1 115.1362 -33.59926  1  1  1
#> 2 115.1362 -33.59937  1  1  1
#> 3 115.1361 -33.59946  1  1  1
#> 4 115.1361 -33.59946  1  1  1
#> 5 115.1361 -33.59946  1  1  1
#> 6 115.1361 -33.59949  1  1  1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you @dieghernan !  I also found `st_crs(shp)$srid` to identify the correct CRS from the file. Replace 4326 with 28350, line  `st_transform(28350) %>%` .. please anyone continue updating for alternatives/explanations.. it was bizarrely difficult to find examples online of this seemingly (now) simple code. Alll perspectives and explanations give a greater understanding.. thanks again for the notations too!

Comment: added `%>% rename(x_reef = X, y_reef = Y)` to @dieghernan great piped `df` code, then generate another `df` from other data "feature" (ie, df1=reef, df2 = Mixed sand and reef),  then `merge(df1, df2)` providing a single `df` with each "feature" (reef, Mixed sand and reef) has their respective lat- column and lon-column, with respective column names per "feature", which also provides each "feature" data as tabulated points.. but table data is to 4-decimal points, thus a more practical 'group_by' solution (?), of points one-degree or greater in difference (to enter in GPS). thanks

Comment: https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/articles/sf1.html